# Crear un query que muestre los usuarios que tomaron una lección de entrenamiento más de una vez

Tags: sql, sql-server

Escribe un query que muestre los usuarios que tomaron una lección de entrenamiento más de una vez en el mismo día agrupado por usuario y lección de entrenamiento, ordenada desde la lección más reciente a la más antigua.

| id_details | id_username | id_training | training date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2015-08-02 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2015-08-03 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 | 2015-08-02 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 | 2015-08-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 2015-08-03 00:00:00.000 |
| 6 | 1 | 1 | 2015-08-02 00:00:00.000 |
| 7 | 3 | 2 | 2015-08-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 8 | 4 | 3 | 2015-08-03 00:00:00.000 |
| 9 | 1 | 4 | 2015-08-03 00:00:00.000 |

La solucion que llegue es :

```
Select id_username, id_training, training_date
From training_details
group by id_training,id_username
Having Count(training_date) > 1
order by training_date
go
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No es un sitio dónde se desarrollen tareas, aporta como código tú avance para poder ayudarte.

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes, hay reglas a seguir para que el orden y la armonía del sitio se mantenga, léelas y practícalas por favor. 2. Las tareas no se resuelven a menos que: el que pregunta tenga un esfuerzo en intento(s) de por medio que se encuentren detallados en la pregunta. 3. Las soluciones van en la parte inferior donde dice "Tu Respuesta", en esa zona incluye todos los pasos a seguir para solucionar tu escenario, podrías ser el héroe de muchos más usuarios que tengan una situación igual o similar. 4. Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que vi el ejemplo que te pasaron funciona sin inconvenientes.
te dejo lo mismo con un ejemplo completo, se contempla que se guarde la

```sql
drop table if exists #test
create table #test (id_details int, id_username int, id_training int,   training date)

insert into #test (id_details , id_username , id_training , training )
values  (1, 1,  1,  '2015-08-02 00:00:00.000'),
        (2, 2,  2,  '2015-08-03 00:00:00.000'),
        (3, 3,  2,  '2015-08-02 11:00:00.000'),
        (4, 4,  2,  '2015-08-04 00:00:00.000'),
        (5, 2,  2,  '2015-08-03 09:00:00.000'),
        (6, 1,  1,  '2015-08-02 00:00:00.000'),
        (7, 3,  2,  '2015-08-04 00:00:00.000'),
        (8, 4,  3,  '2015-08-03 00:00:00.000'),
        (9, 1,  4,  '2015-08-03 00:00:00.000');

select * from #test

Select Id_UserName, Id_Training , convert(char(8), training,112) Fecha, count(1) cant_lecciones
From #test 
Group By Id_UserName, Id_Training, convert(char(8), training,112)
Having Count(1) > 1
Order By 3 Asc
```

Answer (score -1):

Creo que sería algo así...

```
/*Seleccionamos las colúmnas que nos interesan.
El ejercicio pide que muestre a los usuarios con más de una lección.*/
Select Id_UserName, Id_Training, [Training Date] 
From TbTrainings /*No mencionas el nombre de la tabla, así que ésta es a manera de ejemplo*/
/*Agrupamos por las colúmnas por las que queremos contar coincidencias*/
Group By Id_UserName, Id_Training, [Training Date]
/*Obtenemos sólo aquellas cuyo conteo sea mayor a 1 por aquello de (Tomar más de una vez una lección de entrenamiento en el mismo día)*/
Having Count(1) > 1
/*Y ordenamos por fecha (Colúmna 3) para obtener primero los registros más recientes.*/
Order By 3 Asc
```

NOTA: Sinceramente el ejercicio me resulta confuso en estricto sentido práctico, ya que mi intuición me dice que quisieras obtener a los usuarios que han tomado más de un curso el mismo día (Sin importar que se trate del mismo) sin embargo, la redacción del ejercicio y la muestra que nos proporciona, no dejan ver eso... Pero bueno, simplemente es un grito ahogado de mi pragmatísmo.

Saludos!

Comment: Hecho @padaleiana. Saludos!

Comment: Efectivamente amigo es algo confuso es un examen de analista de datos Junior , yo tambien habia llegado a la misma solución que me planteas pero me sale un mensaje de error :                                                                  Column 'training_details.training_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause